# Go SSH key doesn't work with crypto/ssh, but does manually

Tags: go, ssh-keys

I generated a SSH RSA keypair with the `crypto/ssh` package. However, when I try to use it via a script in Go I'm getting the error:

> unable to connect: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate,
>   attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

When I connect to the remote device via CLI, it connects successfully:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/test_key_1 username@172.22.4.1
```

Could I possibly be using the package incorrectly?

**Note: Private key does NOT have a passphrase.**

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    privateKeyFile := "/Users/username/.ssh/test_key_1"
    remoteIP := "172.22.4.1:22"
    user := "username"

    privateKeyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(privateKeyFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    key, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(privateKeyBytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: user,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            // Use the PublicKeys method for remote authentication.
            ssh.PublicKeys(key),
        },
        // using InsecureIgnoreHostKey() for testing purposes
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }

    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", remoteIP, config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to connect: %v", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    fmt.Println("Success!")
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the ssh client is actually connecting with that key? The client will still offer all other known keys too, so you need to connect with `-v` and verify which key was offered and accepted.

Comment: @JimB nice idea. You might be on to something here. Using the `-v` option I see that `debug1: Offering RSA public key: another_key_name`. so it appears it is offering it another key.  Still puzzled why the key pair I generated isn't working. Both Public and Private key appear to be properly formatted, Public key is definitely in Authorized Keys on remote, and Public key matches the output of `ssh-keygen -y -f test_key_1`

Comment: To confirm, I ran `ssh-add -D` to clear out SSH agent and manually connecting no longer works.

Comment: You probably need the debug logs from the server to find out why it’s not being accepted.

Comment: I'm also curios as to how to generated a keypair with the crypto/ssh package, as that package has no helpers or code to generate keys.

Comment: @JimB If you're curious, I solved this issue by using the native SSH package to generate PublicKey from a rsa.PrivateKey.PublicKey (as I should have been doing all along) - https://gist.github.com/devinodaniel/8f9b8a4f31573f428f29ec0e884e6673 . Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

After the long process of component isolation I was finally able to verify why my Key Pairs weren't authenticating. It's due to a custom connivence package I was using that is generating slightly off Public Keys.

I've post on an open issue he had:

https://github.com/ianmcmahon/encoding_ssh/issues/1

In short:

The Public Key that was created using the `EncodePublicKey()` function is as below: (truncated for brevity)

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAA**EAAEAAQAAAg**C2u3I/nbN9jcWDV..

However when running `ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa` the below is created:

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAA**DAQABAAACAQ**C2u3I/nbN9jcWDV...

Notice how the bits in bold are slightly different. This causes SSH authentication to not work.